# Did the people of Srirangam really fight a war ?

Tags: temple, history, sri-vaishnava

I've heard from my grandmother that there was a war fought by the people of srirangam most of whom are Iyengars to get the idol of the srirangam temple deity from the Delhi sultan. I know that there are generally two deities in the temple : The stone one (serpant) and the bronze idol. I also heard that there is actually one more statue which was made when the original was taken away. Also that there is a place in the temple dedicated to the Muslim princess- the daughter of the Sultan. 
What exactly is the story behind this temple ? I mean right from the start : Who got the idol done in the first place and was there really  a war fought by the people of Srirangam ? There are a few accounts online which I've read and alos the mahatmyam. But none of them are comprehensive. I would be glad if someone can give a **comprehensive view of the entire story.** If possible, please do add the source of your information so that it can be verified.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by comprehensive?

Comment: @Keshav Is this the 48 year exile of Azhagiya Manavalan that the question is about? When Srirangam was besieged by the Muslims?

Comment: @Surya This question is about the exile of the Ranganatha statue from Sri Rangam when Sri Rangam was besieged by Muslims.  But what does that have to do with the Azhagiya Manavalan temple?

Comment: Azhagiya Manavalan was the one exiled right? The Moolavar was hidden  by a brick wall.

Comment: I thought the Utsavar was also Azhagiya Manavalan...

Comment: @Surya Sorry, I thought you meant this Azhagiya Manavalan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azhagiya_Manavala_Perumal_Temple Yeah, the Sri Rangam Utsavar was the one that was taken.

Comment: Shri..Read the book of Thiruvarangan ula...by Shrivenugopalan....